# caching services function so you dont repeat calling it

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to initialize some services in angular so that you dont have to repeat calling it? for example

```
services.factory('Util', ['$http', function($http) {
   return {
      countries: function() {
          return $http.get('/utils/countries/');
      },
      ivas: function() {
          return $http.get('/utils/ivas/');
      }
   };
}]);
```

I use this service in several controllers and it takes to long to load all the functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: downvote and no explanation? Nice ...

Comment: you can maybe change the title, because this is not related to service initialization, you just need to cache responses for methods... so it's not a problem of initialization but design

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, ensure the init method is called when you initialize your app by calling `Util.init()` then the data will be taken only once from the server, and you can use anywhere

```
services.factory('Util', ['$http', function($http) {

   var me =  {          
      data: {
          countries: [],
          ivas: []
      },
      init: function() {
          me.data.countries = $http.get('/utils/countries/');
          me.data.ivas = $http.get('/utils/ivas/');
      },
      getCountries: function() {
          return me.data.countries;
      },
      getIvas: function() {
          return me.data.ivas;
      }
   };

 return me;
}]);
```

Comment: 1. defining global `me` variable is not very good idea... 2. I would maybe go even further and populate countries and ivas outside of `me object` when service is registered

Comment: and in the controller how do i put countries and ivas in two diferente scopes?

Comment: $scope.countires = Util.getCountries();// you can assign to any scope you want, the same data is used in all the controllers